# is the merging of data frames necessary here

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame and I would like to plot 3 lines all from the "Value"
vector. The First two lines are the value vector grouped by the "group" and the 3rd line is the UNGROUPED value vector. The way I am currently doing it is by doing 2 calls to DPLYR and creating 2 data frames, then merging them and then plotting the merged data frame. Is there an easier way that avoids 2 calls to DPLYR?

```
d = data.frame(ym = rep(c(20011,20012,20023),3), group = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), value = c(1,2,3,4,2,1,3,3,2)) 

############### 1st call to dplyr  to create plot with 2 lines grouped by "group" 
d2 = d %>%
  group_by(ym,group)  %>%
  summarise(
    Value = mean(value)
  )
d2= as.data.frame(d2)
d2
ggplot(data=d2 , aes(x=ym, y=Value, group=as.factor(group),  colour = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_line()  + geom_point() 


  ###second call to dplyr to create a second data frame just for the UNGROUPED data
  d3 = d %>%
  group_by(ym)  %>%
  summarise(
    Value = mean(value)
  )

  #### merge the  data  TWO frames
d3 =as.data.frame(d3)
d3$group=2
d4 = rbind(d2,d3) 

### plot all 3 lines
ggplot(data=d4 , aes(x=ym, y=Value, group=as.factor(group),  colour = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_line()  + geom_point()
```

Comment: The operation in this case is "stacking" rather than "merging".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a single `dplyr` chain, but (AFAIK) it still requires two separate operations:

```
d2 = bind_rows(
  d %>%
    group_by(ym, group=as.character(group))  %>%
    summarise(Value = mean(value)),
  d %>%
    group_by(ym)  %>%
    summarise(Value = mean(value),
              group = "All"))
```

The code `group=as.character(group)` is necessary to avoid an error when you add `group="All"`, because `bind_rows` won't automatically coerce `group` from numeric to character. (This step is of course unnecessary in cases where the grouping column is already factor or character.)

Then, for plotting you can highlight the average line so that it's separate from the individual groups. We map to `shape` solely to be able to remove the point markers for the `All` line:

```
ggplot(d2 , aes(x=ym, y=Value, colour=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(size=group)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(hcl(c(15,195),100,65), "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,16,NA)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(0.7,0.7,1.5))
```

[image]